# Hangfire: Thread was being aborted

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hangfire

I am using hangfire for background tasks, however a lot of times I'm hit with a following exception:
'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted'. This happens in random code places that are exectued withing the background tasks, sometimes in the middle, sometimes at the end of those methods, which are in a result partially completed. How I should handle such a thing? How i should code around it, or stop it from happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Thread was being aborted" exception raised in excuting Hangfire job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51940607/thread-was-being-aborted-exception-raised-in-excuting-hangfire-job)

Comment: @OwenPauling I will give it a try and see if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

how are you hosting Hangfire? I had issues (but eventually managed to resolve them) when hosting Hangfire in IIS. One place to look for errors is in the Windows EventViewer.
Current guess is that the parent thread was stopped (either from IIS or some exception).

Also, Hangfire uses the DEBUG log4net logger. You can use that to get more detailed error logs from Hangfire.

Without more detailed information, that is all I can contribute.